# Lambda Expression: inside or outside of foreach statement?

Tags: c#, loops, lambda

I am wondering about efficiency when I am coding using a lambda expression, imagine this case:

**First way**

```
foreach (Section section in formAssigned.Sections.Where(x => !x.Deleted))
{
//code
}
```

**Second way**

```
var list = formAssigned.Sections.Where(x => !x.Deleted)
foreach (Section section in list)
{
//code
}
```

My question is, the foreach statement will get the enumerator once or it will get it in every loop using the first way?

Comment: there is no difference. !

Comment: There is no difference, because compiler calculates `formAssigned.Sections.Where(x => !x.Deleted)` and puts it before your loop in IL code

Comment: Please narrow your question to include how you are defining efficiency. The best way to determine this [is to measure it](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: In the second way you add a new variable to hold your query. The difference is the same as between `Console.Write("foo")` and `string foo="foo";Console.Write(foo)`

Comment: @HereticMonkey A nice reading.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that in the first way, for each loop, then it was necessary to calculate the query "formAssigned.Sections.Where(x => !x.Deleted)" but if you are saying that using the second way is the same as the first way then it is ok.

Comment: formAssigned.Sections.Where(x => !x.Deleted) is not calculated before loop, it is "calculated" when loop call MoveNext().

Comment: Try to write your own implementation of `foreach` that actually computes the expression multiple times, just to see what that code would look like.

Comment: @OndřejKubíček got it, so basically first and second solution are the same because of this reason, right?

Comment: Yeah, they are the same. The only difference is that with second way in Debug you'll have 1 more local variable in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, roughly speaking `foreach` loop gets enumerator object and iterates the collection using `MoveNext` method.

So think of it as though you have code like this:

```
var enumerator = formAssigned.Sections.Where(x => !x.Deleted).GetEnumerator();
// some code with enumerator (this is what you have in body of foreach loop)
```

And

```
var query = formAssigned.Sections.Where(x => !x.Deleted); // returns IEnumerable<T>
var enumerator = query.GetEnumerator();
// some code with enumerator
```

Comment: @TheIE100 That's not what your question is currently asking.  If that's what you actually want to know, you should edit it to actually ask that.

Comment: @TheIE100 As Servy correctly pointed out it is a *different* question. Edit your question or create a new one